# Select rows with multiple same values using COUNT in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL database like this:

```
item    color   size
t-shirt blue    M
jumper  black   L
jumper  black   L
t-shirt blue    M
```

I want to select the rows that have the same value, so I get output like this:

```
item    color   size  total
t-shirt blue    M     2
jumper  black   L     2
```

This is what I've tried:

```
SELECT item, COUNT(*) as total FROM table_name GROUP BY color,size HAVING total >= 1
```

But, my query doesn't give the results I want. What is the query I can use to obtain the output?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you have an attempt? Your question title leads me to believe you're on the right track. `GROUP BY` on every column, `COUNT` for the last.

Comment: @TylerRoper yes, but my query not give the output like I want

Comment: We can't help you correct your query without seeing it :) It may be a simple query, but StackOverflow isn't really a code-writing resource; we prefer to *help* you instead of doing it *for* you. Please edit your question and share your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use *count* with a *group by*. Something similar to below:

```
select item, color, size,  count(*) as total from table_name group by item, color, size;
```